# sending multiple sms in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my web applicatin i am using api for sending sms, ya it is working fine for single phone number, but my requirement is  i want to send sms to two phone numbers(mobile numbers)can u help me.when user come to my site and register autometically admin will get sms alert, now i want to send sms at the same time.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        mobile =Server.HtmlEncode ( txtMobile.Text);
        message = Server.HtmlEncode(txtMessage.Text);
        username = Server.HtmlEncode(txtName.Text);
        password = Server.HtmlEncode(txtPassword.Text);
        domian = Server.HtmlEncode(txtDomain.Text);
        string result = apicall("http://"+domian+"/pushsms.php?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&sender=&to="+mobile+"&message="+message);
        if (!result.StartsWith("Wrong Username or Password"))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "success", "alert('Message Sent')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "success", "alert('Message Sending Failed')", true);
        }
sentMail()

    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

public void sentMail()
    {
      string   mobile = "9701098107";
     string    message = "test";
       string  username = "xxx";
      string   password = "yyyy";
      string   domian = "smsftt.com";
        string result1 = apicall("http://" + domian + "/pushsms.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&sender=&to=" + mobile + "&message=" + message);
    }

```
public string apicall(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    try
    {

        HttpWebResponse httpres = (HttpWebResponse)httpreq.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpres.GetResponseStream());

        string results = sr.ReadToEnd();

        sr.Close();
        return results;



    }
    catch
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the numbers are stored in a List<string> then can you not just call the single sending routine foreach of the phone numbers in the list?

Comment: Mr.WestDiscGolf actually when ever user came to my site and register autometically admin will get sms alert, now i want to send sms to the user also at the same time. i am placing the code please check it.i am editing my question please check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not just as simple as making that apicall again with different details? Change the mobile number you pass in and job done...

Comment: i write a method in that i call that api code when first sms is sent then second one called but it is not going

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: I don't know who it is you are using to send the sms but is it possible they limit you in some way so you can't send more than one in a limited amount of time (eg one a second). This seems more likely to be where your problem is than in the code you've displayed above.

Alternatively there are bugs in your apicall method and you'll need to show us the code for that. Without the whole picture its very hard to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: Your code looks fine. I'd suggest to debug you analyze more closely what the response you get back from the calls is. You only check for "Wrong Username or password". Try putting the result into the alert when it fails so you can see precisely what the server is saying. I'd guess it is something like "too many calls" and is designed to stop rapid automation of SMS sending. If this is the case you'll have to find out what the time limit is and make some kind of queueing system to make sure your calls don't go too rapidly. Another test would be two simultaneous registrations.

Comment: ya it is working fine Mr.Chris i am getting two messages thank you for response and every thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code its working fine for me , keep the below code in function call that function with the multiple mobile numbers separated in CSV

```
 string stringpost = "Here username password and type of sms as querystring";
            HttpWebRequest objWebRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse objWebResponse = null;
            StreamWriter objStreamWriter = null;
            StreamReader objStreamReader = null;
            try
            {
                string stringResult = null;

                objWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://'your sms api'");

                objWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                objWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(objWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
                objStreamWriter.Write(stringpost);
                objStreamWriter.Flush();
                objStreamWriter.Close();

                objWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();

                objWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();

                objStreamReader = new StreamReader(objWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                stringResult = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                objStreamReader.Close();
                return (stringResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((objStreamWriter != null))
                {
                    objStreamWriter.Close();
                }
                if ((objStreamReader != null))
                {
                    objStreamReader.Close();
                }
                objWebRequest = null;
                objWebResponse = null;
            }
```